# Integer to Bit in SQL

Tags: sql, integer, firebird, bit

I have an `Integer` field, and I need to divide it into `Bits to the SQL(Firebird)`. For each byte of the Integer field should be a new field. For Example:

```
Integer field: 7 = 00000111

Bit 1 field1: 1  
Bit 2 field2: 1  
Bit 3 field3: 1  
Bit 4 Field4: 0
Bit 5 Field5: 0
Bit 6 Field6: 0
Bit 7 Field7: 0
Bit 8 Field8: 0
```

anyone know how to do this in Firebird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`BIN_AND`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-bin_and.html) function:

```
SELECT 
   bin_and(field, 1) as bit1, 
   bin_and(field, 2) as bit2, 
   bin_and(field, 4) as bit3,
   bin_and(field, 8) as bit4,
   ... 
FROM T
```